# Minimal example of wrapping C code with Cython- passing int and struct

Tags: python, c, cython, word-wrap

The code that I show below works, *but I am not exactly sure why*.

I am using:

- Mac OSX 10.8.5
- brewed Python 2.7.5
- Cython 0.20.2

This code is taken primarily from [this video tutorial](http://pyvideo.org/video/1692/cython-vs-swig-fight) and [git page](https://github.com/mkohler/cython_swig), but unfortunately did not work for me 'out of the box'.

The goal of this wrapping to provide access through Python to a trivial C function, which accepts either integers or a structure of integers and adds them together.

There are 5 files needed for this, described below:

- `adder.c`: C code of the two adder functions: *add* (scalar inputs) and *pair_add* (struct inputs)
- `adder.h`: header file for adder.c
- `c_adder.pxd`: a cython header file- essentially tells cython which parts of the main header file to pay attention to
- `cy_adder.pyx`: the cython code used to define both functions in the python namespace
- `setup.py`: a distutils file which performs the compiling of the cython code

and the process produces two files

- `c_adder.c`: an intermediate cython c file
- `c_adder.so`: the python module which can be imported into a namespace

The input files are below:

**adder.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "adder.h"

int
pair_add(PAIR * ppair) {
    return ppair->x + ppair->y;
}

int
add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

**adder.h**

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} PAIR;

int pair_add(PAIR * ppair);
int add(int, int);
```

**c_adder.pxd**

```
cdef extern from "adder.h":

    ctypedef struct PAIR:
        int x
        int y


    int add(int x, int y)
    int pair_add(PAIR * ppair)
```

**cy_adder.pyx**

```
cimport c_adder

def add(x, y):
    return c_adder.add(x, y)

def pair_add(x, y):
    cdef c_adder.PAIR pair
    pair.x = x
    pair.y = y
    return c_adder.pair_add(&pair)
```

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize


ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("cy_adder", ["cy_adder.pyx",'adder.c'])])


setup(
  name = 'Hello world app',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

I was able to successfully create a .so file by running

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

In the same directory as the above files. It is then possible to load `cy_adder` into the namespace of a python interpreter.

---

#### The question

In the setup declaration, I have included `adder.c` as an auxiliary module.

**If I don't do this** I get the following error when I import the `.so` file:

```
ImportError: dlopen(./cy_adder.so, 2): Symbol not found: _add
  Referenced from: ./cy_adder.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ./cy_adder.so
```

Is there a step that I am missing which would mean that I don't need to explicitly pass `adder.c` along with my setup command? Am I opening myself up to some potential instability by doing this?

Comment: There are many examples in the official docs that add the C file to the array, as you did. There is also a way to add it to the pyx with a special comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `adder.c` file needs to be referenced somewhere so it knows where to find the implementation of `add`.  As you discovered, listing `adder.c` as an additional source file works.  A more common way to use external (shared) C libraries is to compile it as libadder.so and link it via the `libraries` parameter in your Extension declaration.

For something this simple you could also just write

```
cdef extern from "adder.c":   # note the .c
    int add(int x, int y)
    ...
```

or put the entire implementation in the .h file.